# Margin-top doesnt change position

Tags: html, css

I wanted to move an element up, I tried with margin-top, but it seems it doesn't work.

```css
#nextquestion {
  margin-left: 80%;
  width: 15%;
  background-color: #333333;
  height: 40%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 0.01%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#question1 {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  font-size: 31px;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: #161624; width: 100%; height: 20%; vertical-align: bottom ;">
  <a href="#" id="question1" style="display: inline-block;">Question 1/X</a>
  <button id="nextquestion">Next Question</button>
</div>
```

I have added display: inline-block, but it didn't change anything.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAmXW.png)
Margin-top: -..., doesn't change a lot

Comment: that's a very tiny value, it will do nothing

Comment: Also, to move an element *up* you need a negative margin-top.

Comment: If i use margin-top: -10%, it changed a little bit, but after that, if i write like 15% it didnt change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the right way to do it in my opinion. Using negative margins is not a good practice. I would instead use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to achieve it:

```css
#question-container {
  background-color: #161624;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 20%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 3rem;
}

#nextquestion {
  width: 15%;
  min-width: 120px;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
}

#question1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div id="question-container">
  <a id="question1" style="display: inline-block;">Question 1/X</a>
  <button id="nextquestion">Next Question</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  in gemany we say I kiss your heart! It works

Comment: No problem. In Greece we say in response: "It costs nothing" :)

Comment: In the Netherlands we charge you then 20 euros. :-) just kidding :D

Comment: Don't forget the administration costs @Dorvalla which is an extra 7,99

Answer (score 0):

Try to add position & top.

add this in your code:

```
position: relative;
top: -36px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with this code :

```css
div{
    background-color: #161624;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: flex;
}
#question1 {
    color: white;
    margin: 40px;
    font-size: 31px;
}
#nextquestion {
    width: 15%;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 44px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a id="question1" style="display: inline-block;">Question 1/X</a>
    <button id="nextquestion">Next Question</button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flex and then `align-self`:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container{
  background-color: #161624;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
#container div:first-child{
  width: 40%;
}
#container div:last-child{
  width: 35%;
  align-self: flex-start; /*here! remove this if you want placed in the center vertically.*/
}
#nextquestion {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#question1 {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  font-size: 31px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div><a href="#" id="question1">Question 1/X</a></div>
  <div><button id="nextquestion">Next Question</button></div>
</div>
```